Why can't I deform a cylinder to a curve I created?



[]
5

As you can see, I have a curve and a cylinder. When I add enough loop cuts to the cylinder and apply a Curve modifier, it takes a very strange form and no matter what deform axis I choose, it doesn't take the shape of the curve. I put images with some of the deform axes above.
Any help would be very appreciated.

That image is too small to be readable here. I'd suggest you add individual images created using Blender's built-in Window > Save Screenshot menu rather than using a moving image.

@JohnEason Thanks for the feedback. I did so.

Try applying the Scale to your cylinder with Ctrl-S > Scale in Object mode. There's a quick tutorial on using a curve modifier with a cylinder here.

@JohnEason It seems like there was a problem with the curve. I recreated the curve and it solved the problem. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Glad to hear you've sorted it!
